# What is gid in OpenStreetMap data model?

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, pgrouting

I'm using an old code written by an ex-fellow and I wonder what is GID in OSM? The gid is basically used everywhere. The project uses PostGIS and PgRouting. Any pointers to that?

I know this is a naive question but I need a start. Thanks.

As an example, this method comes from [this](https://code.google.com/p/gisgraphy/source/browse/trunk/gisgraphy/src/main/java/com/gisgraphy/domain/repository/IOpenStreetMapDao.java?spec=svn115&r=115) interface.

```
/**
     * @param gid the gid of the openstreetmap entity we want to retrieve
     * @return the OpenstreetMap entity or null if not found
     */
    public OpenStreetMap getByGid(final Long gid) ;
```

Comment: I think it is just referring to a Global (unique) ID -"Every object in the OSM database has a unique ID. It is assigned by the OSM database when the object is created. Object IDs are, for example, used to relate ways to the nodes they contain." from [OSM Wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Import/Software).

Comment: There is no such thing as a global unique ID in OSM. All nodes, ways and relations have an ID but this ID is only unique *within* the element type. A node can have the same ID as a way or a relation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be the **Road link ID**  : http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/topology.html

Comment: So as far as I understand, this is a small road segment that starts with a node and ends with a node. Right?

Answer (score -1):

Unique record ID, i have two imports and same street/way is different gid in each.

Comment: Are you saying that Unique record ID should be used instead of GID? What is the name of the Unique record ID?

Comment: I did twice same  data import and gid was always different for same record, to me it look like an unique id for row in db.

Answer (score -2):

"get ID" I would say.
Just like gLon, gLat etc.

Comment: Hi Doruk, Welcome to GIS Stack Exchange :) One line answers are generally discouraged, and one liners that are are just a guess doubly so. We strive to build quality answers that will still be useful some time from now.

Comment: Will do my best next time..

Comment: I have confidence in that Doruk. :) We were all new at some point, and the Stack Exchange approach is quite different from many systems that have come before it. Read the [help](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help), walk through the tutorial, and you'll be doing fine in short order. Just remember that up & down votes are not about *you*, they're about *the post*.