# OSM Data 'gid' column

Tags: openstreetmap, topology

Eventually I came to know that in order to use `pgr_createTopology` function to create topology network on my imported OSM data (using pg_routing and PostGIS on postgresql), apart from `the_geom` geometry column I also need the `gid` integer column which is shipped along with the OSM geometry data.

`SELECT pgr_createTopology('ways', 0.00001, 'the_geom', 'gid');`

But what is this `gid` column? I need to run the same `pgr_createTopology` function on my custom `linestring geometry` table but I don't know about this `gid` column.

Comment: Did you check if the gid of a way equals OSM's way id? I.e. you could check if *http://www.openstreetmap.org/way/<ID>* shows the same object as in your local database.

Comment: Please repost the correct url. This one is not working.

Comment: Sure it is, you have to replace *<ID>* with the ID you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, for example `http://www.openstreetmap.org/way/114006424` is showing the correct way on the OSM website. But this `114006424` is my db `osm_id` but I am looking for `gid` since `pgr_createTopology()` asks for the `gid` only.

Comment: So that means the `gid` is not contained in the OSM database but some artificial number generated by some tool your are using.

Comment: But after installing the `pgrouting-workshop`, now I have a sample dataset and I can see this `gid` values in the `sampledata_notopo.sql` file. It means that the `gid` was shipped along with the long-lat data from OSM site.

Comment: No, OSM doesn't know any `gid`. It just knows an ID for every [element](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Elements) (node, way and relation). Also, OSM doesn't offer any SQL files. This file has been generated by a tool which probably also added the `gid`.

Comment: hmm. Well, to import my `xyz.osm` data I am using `osm2pgrouting`. I think this `Pgrouting` PostGIS extension is doing something. But then how could I populate the `gid` column for my custom road vector lines? Because I need this particular `gid` for `pgr_createTopology()` to create topology for my own generated road lines?

Comment: @scai and @Gabor My bad! There was some error in my geometry column's `SRID` and I thought `gid` to be the reason for my `pgr_createTopology()`'s error. Thanks by the way.

Answer (score 1):

It's something like geometry ID, a unique ID to identify each feature in the OSM database. Further references:

[What is gid in OpenStreetMap data model?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/67527/what-is-gid-in-openstreetmap-data-model)

http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/topology.html

Comment: hmm. But when I made a new column in my `ways` table like this `ALTER TABLE ways ADD COLUMN id1 SERIAL;` and then run the command `SELECT pgr_createTopology('ways', 0.00001, 'the_geom', 'id1');`, it gave me `ERROR: Condition is not correct` error. Logically there shouldn't be any error, because now I am using `id1` as my Unique ID column.

Comment: Is your `id1` column the primary key? The description of `pgr_createTopology` (http://docs.pgrouting.org/dev/src/common/doc/functions/create_topology.html) states that the `gid_cname` is the "primary key column name of the network table".

Comment: I made `id1` as my primary key but still it's not working. By the way, even the by default `gid` column is also not the primary key.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is in its original environment (the OSM database). When you export OSM data, you won't get the rules or constraints of the database, just the raw attribute and geometry data.

Unfortunately, I haven't encountered the PgRouting plugin of PGSQL yet, so I can't help you out furthermore. Furthermore the other problem isn't directly related to the original question, so I suggest you to ask a new question directly about the `pgr_createTopology` function.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I'll post a new question targeting `pgr_createTopology()` function.